# "Short read block" error trying to boot RHEL

Tags: filesystems, boot, rhel, ext3

I changed my network configurations from static IP to DHCP and removed the DNS entry, etc.

Then I rebooted the computer, but am now unable to boot, I get an error message along the lines of "short read block filesystem ext3". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've unfortunately had unrelated disk corruption. Your hard disk is likely dying or dead.

I hope you have backups of anything important.